# Correct pronunciation of number words ending in -g? Such as "zwanzig"

Tags: pronunciation

What is the correct pronunciation of words ending in *-g*? Such as:

- heftig
- zwanzig
- lustig
- and so on...

In many films and TV series I heard something like "lustich", "zwanzich" and so forth, however, while speaking to a native German, they told me it is wrong pronunciation and that it should be "lustik", "heftik", like the final sound of the word "Tag".

Is *-ch* or *-k* the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Die korrekte Aussprache ist *-ch*, nach [Wikpedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BChnendeutsch) und §35 Grammatikduden. *-k* ist aber die Standardaussprache im Süden. Es gibt auch Mischformen, aus irgendeinem Grunde spreche ich es mal so, mal so aus.